# How to add header and footer to a ListView while swipe?

Tags: android, listview, header, footer, swipe

I want to add a header view and a footer view in a ListView while swipe down and swipe up respectively. I want a pull to refresh like action without animation. I tried with touch event ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN . I am using the following code .

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v==listView){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_header, listView, false);
            ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_footer, listView, false);
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0){

                    if(listView.getHeaderViewsCount()==0)
                    {
                        listView.addHeaderView(header);

                    }

                }
                else{ 
                    RemoveFooter(footer);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                listView.removeHeaderView(header);
                if(listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getCount()-1)
                {
                    if(listView.getFooterViewsCount()==0){
                        listView.addFooterView(footer);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    removeHeader(header);   
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;

            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It is not working in the desired way. While referencing pull to refresh library I saw that it takes y coordinates. If I should do the same,then how I will do that? else what should I do in order to obtain the requirement?